# Why does CMake neglects source files?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, code-coverage, gcov

The `CMakeLists.txt` file I wrote, unfortunately, create coverage statistics solely for header files and test scripts, but not for the source files. I would, however, like to heave coverage information for the source files. What am I doing wrong?

As an example, here is the header file: `class.h`

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class StrVec{
    public:
    StrVec(const std::string&);
    void print() {std::cout << vec[0] << std::endl;}

    private:
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
};
```

The source file is `class.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "class.h"

StrVec::StrVec(const std::string& s): vec({s}) {}
```

And the "test" file is `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "class.h"

int main() {
    std::string s("test");
    StrVec str_vec(s);
    str_vec.print();
}
```

The `CmakeLists.txt` file I wrote is:

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project (StrVec)
set(LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
SET (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER             "/usr/bin/g++")

set(${LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME}_SRC
    class.cpp
)

set(${LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME}_HDR
    class.h
)

add_library(${LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME} SHARED ${${LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME}_SRC})
add_compile_options(--coverage -O0)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main StrVec --coverage)
```

When I compile the code and run the program, `lcov` only finds `main.cpp.gcda`  and not `class.cpp`. The coverage statistics thus include only the header file `class.h` and `main.cpp` *but not* `class.cpp`. How can I modify `CMakeList.txt` to obtain coverage statistics for `class.cpp`?

I read several `cmake` and `gcov` documents and I had the impression that I specifically need to request coverage for the `_SRC` files. However, I could not figure out how to do that. Can somebody kindly point out what I can do?

Comment: You should try using [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html#command:target_compile_options) to add those coverage flags to each target (library and executable). `add_compile_options` may only apply to the executable target in your example.

Comment: Thanks @squareskittles for the kind and helpful comment! Indeed, using `target_compile_options` turned out to be useful. I had to add `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -O0 --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")` and `target_compile_options(${LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC "--coverage" )`. With only the `target_compile_options` the linker complained `main: hidden_symbol gcov__init is referenced by DSO`. Do you have any ideas why I needed to add these two lines?

Comment: Glad it helped! Using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is also a more global approach to setting compiler options, and can apply to multiple projects. I tend to try to use the target-specific commands when possible, to keep the extra options localized. But I think you should be able to add all the options to either `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` or `target_compile_options` to get the desired effect. For completeness, you should make an answer out of your working code, and mark as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @squareskitties help, I managed to solve the problem. I just didn't pass all required compile options. The following `CMakeLists.txt` worked:

```
c++
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project (StrVec)
set(LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
SET (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER             "/usr/bin/g++")

set(${LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME}_SRC
    class.cpp
)

set(${LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME}_HDR
    class.h
)

add_library(${LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME} SHARED ${${LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME}_SRC})
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -O0 --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main StrVec --coverage)
```