# setup gcovr with cmake-How can I Get Code coverage recursively on all static libraries

Tags: cmake, gcov, gcovr

I have setup gcovr to get code coverage on my c++ project which is quite complex in terms of hierarchy of nested static libraries.

One approach I tried was to include required compile options (`-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping -fPIC -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`) and link target libraries flags (`-fprofile-instr-generate`) on the target for which coverage is supposed to be calculated. But this doesn't include the code from child static library. 
To resolve that I added the flags to children static library which worked but this doesn't work for grandchildren & later on.

How can I setup the cMake correctly to get code coverage for all the classes irrespective of their library position?

Comment: You can look at this question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330684/why-does-cmake-neglects-source-files

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to explicitly call add_code_coverage function for the static libraries.
Finally ended up writing following wrapper method:

```
function(target_link_libraries_with_coverage targetName library)
    target_link_libraries(${targetName} ${library})
    add_code_coverage(${library})
endfunction()
```

This should be called instead of target_link_libraries when linking the libraries for which you need coverage.

Note: add_code_coverage is adding required compile options